# create hierarchical table in oracle database

Tags: oracle, business-intelligence, oracle-bi

this is my query to construct a hierarchical table to use in oracle bi 
actually I use it in my subject area.
but sometimes when I drill down with value label my analytics is display no result but when I drill with header label it work fine!!!!
also when I filter level its display no result 
would you please help me.

```
with kol_power as
 (select level                        lvl,
         p.id,
         p.parameter_name             title,
         p.parent_system_parameter_id parentid,
         p.ip                         hierarchicode,
         system_id
    from EVAL_sys_paramter p
  connect by prior id = parent_system_parameter_id
   start with parent_system_parameter_id is null),
l1 as
 (select * from kol_power where lvl = 1),
l2 as
 (select *
    from kol_power k
   where k.lvl = 2
     and (parentid, system_id) in (select id, system_id from l1)),
l3 as
 (select *
    from kol_power k
   where k.lvl = 3
     and (parentid, system_id) in (select id, system_id from l2)),
l4 as
 (select *
    from kol_power k
   where k.lvl = 4
     and (parentid, system_id) in (select id, system_id from l3)),
l5 as
 (select *
    from kol_power k
   where k.lvl = 5
     and (parentid, system_id) in (select id, system_id from l4)),
l6 as
 (select *
    from kol_power k
   where k.lvl = 6
     and (parentid, system_id) in (select id, system_id from l5)),
l7 as
 (select *
    from kol_power k
   where k.lvl = 7
     and (parentid, system_id) in (select id, system_id from l6)),
l8 as
 (select *
    from kol_power k
   where k.lvl = 8
     and (parentid, system_id) in (select id, system_id from l7)),
l9 as
 (select *
    from kol_power k
   where k.lvl = 9
     and (parentid, system_id) in (select id, system_id from l8)),
r9 as
 (select l1.id            l1_id,
         l1.title         l1_title,
         l1.hierarchicode l1_hierarchicode,
         l2.id            l2_id,
         l2.title         l2_title,
         l2.hierarchicode l2_hierarchicode,
         l3.id            l3_id,
         l3.title         l3_title,
         l3.hierarchicode l3_hierarchicode,
         l4.id            l4_id,
         l4.title         l4_title,
         l4.hierarchicode l4_hierarchicode,
         l5.id            l5_id,
         l5.title         l5_title,
         l5.hierarchicode l5_hierarchicode,
         l6.id            l6_id,
         l6.title         l6_title,
         l6.hierarchicode l6_hierarchicode,
         l7.id            l7_id,
         l7.title         l7_title,
         l7.hierarchicode l7_hierarchicode,
         l8.id            l8_id,
         l8.title         l8_title,
         l8.hierarchicode l8_hierarchicode,
         l9.id            l9_id,
         l9.title         l9_title,
         l9.hierarchicode l9_hierarchicode,
         l2.system_id
    from l1, l2, l3, l4, l5, l6, l7, l8, l9
   where l2.parentid = l1.id
     and l2.system_id = l1.system_id
     and l3.parentid = l2.id
     and l3.system_id = l2.system_id
     and l4.parentid = l3.id
     and l4.system_id = l3.system_id
     and l5.parentid = l4.id
     and l5.system_id = l4.system_id
     and l6.parentid = l5.id
     and l6.system_id = l5.system_id
     and l7.parentid = l6.id
     and l7.system_id = l6.system_id
     and l8.parentid = l7.id
     and l8.system_id = l7.system_id
     and l9.parentid = l8.id
     and l9.system_id = l8.system_id

  ),
r8 as
 (select l1.id            l1_id,
         l1.title         l1_title,
         l1.hierarchicode l1_hierarchicode,
         l2.id            l2_id,
         l2.title         l2_title,
         l2.hierarchicode l2_hierarchicode,
         l3.id            l3_id,
         l3.title         l3_title,
         l3.hierarchicode l3_hierarchicode,
         l4.id            l4_id,
         l4.title         l4_title,
         l4.hierarchicode l4_hierarchicode,
         l5.id            l5_id,
         l5.title         l5_title,
         l5.hierarchicode l5_hierarchicode,
         l6.id            l6_id,
         l6.title         l6_title,
         l6.hierarchicode l6_hierarchicode,
         l7.id            l7_id,
         l7.title         l7_title,
         l7.hierarchicode l7_hierarchicode,
         l8.id            l8_id,
         l8.title         l8_title,
         l8.hierarchicode l8_hierarchicode,
         null             l9_id,
         null             l9_title,
         null             l9_hierarchicode,
         l2.system_id
    from l1, l2, l3, l4, l5, l6, l7, l8
   where l2.parentid = l1.id
     and l2.system_id = l1.system_id
     and l3.parentid = l2.id
     and l3.system_id = l2.system_id
     and l4.parentid = l3.id
     and l4.system_id = l3.system_id
     and l5.parentid = l4.id
     and l5.system_id = l4.system_id
     and l6.parentid = l5.id
     and l6.system_id = l5.system_id
     and l7.parentid = l6.id
     and l7.system_id = l6.system_id
     and l8.parentid = l7.id
     and l8.system_id = l7.system_id),
r7 as
 (select l1.id            l1_id,
         l1.title         l1_title,
         l1.hierarchicode l1_hierarchicode,
         l2.id            l2_id,
         l2.title         l2_title,
         l2.hierarchicode l2_hierarchicode,
         l3.id            l3_id,
         l3.title         l3_title,
         l3.hierarchicode l3_hierarchicode,
         l4.id            l4_id,
         l4.title         l4_title,
         l4.hierarchicode l4_hierarchicode,
         l5.id            l5_id,
         l5.title         l5_title,
         l5.hierarchicode l5_hierarchicode,
         l6.id            l6_id,
         l6.title         l6_title,
         l6.hierarchicode l6_hierarchicode,
         l7.id            l7_id,
         l7.title         l7_title,
         l7.hierarchicode l7_hierarchicode,
         null             l8_id,
         null             l8_title,
         null             l8_hierarchicode,
         null             l9_id,
         null             l9_title,
         null             l9_hierarchicode,
         l2.system_id
    from l1, l2, l3, l4, l5, l6, l7
   where l2.parentid = l1.id
     and l2.system_id = l1.system_id
     and l3.parentid = l2.id
     and l3.system_id = l2.system_id
     and l4.parentid = l3.id
     and l4.system_id = l3.system_id
     and l5.parentid = l4.id
     and l5.system_id = l4.system_id
     and l6.parentid = l5.id
     and l6.system_id = l5.system_id
     and l7.parentid = l6.id
     and l7.system_id = l6.system_id),
r6 as
 (select l1.id            l1_id,
         l1.title         l1_title,
         l1.hierarchicode l1_hierarchicode,
         l2.id            l2_id,
         l2.title         l2_title,
         l2.hierarchicode l2_hierarchicode,
         l3.id            l3_id,
         l3.title         l3_title,
         l3.hierarchicode l3_hierarchicode,
         l4.id            l4_id,
         l4.title         l4_title,
         l4.hierarchicode l4_hierarchicode,
         l5.id            l5_id,
         l5.title         l5_title,
         l5.hierarchicode l5_hierarchicode,
         l6.id            l6_id,
         l6.title         l6_title,
         l6.hierarchicode l6_hierarchicode,
         null             l7_id,
         null             l7_title,
         null             l7_hierarchicode,
         null             l8_id,
         null             l8_title,
         null             l8_hierarchicode,
         null             l9_id,
         null             l9_title,
         null             l9_hierarchicode,
         l2.system_id
    from l1, l2, l3, l4, l5, l6
   where l2.parentid = l1.id
     and l2.system_id = l1.system_id
     and l3.parentid = l2.id
     and l3.system_id = l2.system_id
     and l4.parentid = l3.id
     and l4.system_id = l3.system_id
     and l5.parentid = l4.id
     and l5.system_id = l4.system_id
     and l6.parentid = l5.id
     and l6.system_id = l5.system_id)

,
r5 as
 (select l1.id            l1_id,
         l1.title         l1_title,
         l1.hierarchicode l1_hierarchicode,
         l2.id            l2_id,
         l2.title         l2_title,
         l2.hierarchicode l2_hierarchicode,
         l3.id            l3_id,
         l3.title         l3_title,
         l3.hierarchicode l3_hierarchicode,
         l4.id            l4_id,
         l4.title         l4_title,
         l4.hierarchicode l4_hierarchicode,
         l5.id            l5_id,
         l5.title         l5_title,
         l5.hierarchicode l5_hierarchicode,
         null             l6_id,
         null             l6_title,
         null             l6_hierarchicode,
         null             l7_id,
         null             l7_title,
         null             l7_hierarchicode,
         null             l8_id,
         null             l8_title,
         null             l8_hierarchicode,
         null             l9_id,
         null             l9_title,
         null             l9_hierarchicode,
         l2.system_id
    from l1, l2, l3, l4, l5
   where l2.parentid = l1.id
     and l2.system_id = l1.system_id
     and l3.parentid = l2.id
     and l3.system_id = l2.system_id
     and l4.parentid = l3.id
     and l4.system_id = l3.system_id
     and l5.parentid = l4.id
     and l5.system_id = l4.system_id)

,
r4 as
 (select l1.id            l1_id,
         l1.title         l1_title,
         l1.hierarchicode l1_hierarchicode,
         l2.id            l2_id,
         l2.title         l2_title,
         l2.hierarchicode l2_hierarchicode,
         l3.id            l3_id,
         l3.title         l3_title,
         l3.hierarchicode l3_hierarchicode,
         l4.id            l4_id,
         l4.title         l4_title,
         l4.hierarchicode l4_hierarchicode,
         null             l5_id,
         null             l5_title,
         null             l5_hierarchicode,
         null             l6_id,
         null             l6_title,
         null             l6_hierarchicode,
         null             l7_id,
         null             l7_title,
         null             l7_hierarchicode,
         null             l8_id,
         null             l8_title,
         null             l8_hierarchicode,
         null             l9_id,
         null             l9_title,
         null             l9_hierarchicode,
         l2.system_id
    from l1, l2, l3, l4
   where l2.parentid = l1.id
     and l2.system_id = l1.system_id
     and l3.parentid = l2.id
     and l3.system_id = l2.system_id
     and l4.parentid = l3.id
     and l4.system_id = l3.system_id)

,
r3 as
 (select l1.id            l1_id,
         l1.title         l1_title,
         l1.hierarchicode l1_hierarchicode,
         l2.id            l2_id,
         l2.title         l2_title,
         l2.hierarchicode l2_hierarchicode,
         l3.id            l3_id,
         l3.title         l3_title,
         l3.hierarchicode l3_hierarchicode,
         null             l4_id,
         null             l4_title,
         null             l4_hierarchicode,
         null             l5_id,
         null             l5_title,
         null             l5_hierarchicode,
         null             l6_id,
         null             l6_title,
         null             l6_hierarchicode,
         null             l7_id,
         null             l7_title,
         null             l7_hierarchicode,
         null             l8_id,
         null             l8_title,
         null             l8_hierarchicode,
         null             l9_id,
         null             l9_title,
         null             l9_hierarchicode,
         l2.system_id
    from l1, l2, l3
   where l2.parentid = l1.id
     and l2.system_id = l1.system_id
     and l3.parentid = l2.id
     and l3.system_id = l2.system_id)

,
r2 as
 (select l1.id            l1_id,
         l1.title         l1_title,
         l1.hierarchicode l1_hierarchicode,
         l2.id            l2_id,
         l2.title         l2_title,
         l2.hierarchicode l2_hierarchicode,
         null             l3_id,
         null             l3_title,
         null             l3_hierarchicode,
         null             l4_id,
         null             l4_title,
         null             l4_hierarchicode,
         null             l5_id,
         null             l5_title,
         null             l5_hierarchicode,
         null             l6_id,
         null             l6_title,
         null             l6_hierarchicode,
         null             l7_id,
         null             l7_title,
         null             l7_hierarchicode,
         null             l8_id,
         null             l8_title,
         null             l8_hierarchicode,
         null             l9_id,
         null             l9_title,
         null             l9_hierarchicode,
         l2.system_id
    from l1, l2
   where l2.parentid = l1.id
     and l2.system_id = l1.system_id)

,
r1 as
 (select l1.id            l1_id,
         l1.title         l1_title,
         l1.hierarchicode l1_hierarchicode,
         null             l2_id,
         null             l2_title,
         null             l2_hierarchicode,
         null             l3_id,
         null             l3_title,
         null             l3_hierarchicode,
         null             l4_id,
         null             l4_title,
         null             l4_hierarchicode,
         null             l5_id,
         null             l5_title,
         null             l5_hierarchicode,
         null             l6_id,
         null             l6_title,
         null             l6_hierarchicode,
         null             l7_id,
         null             l7_title,
         null             l7_hierarchicode,
         null             l8_id,
         null             l8_title,
         null             l8_hierarchicode,
         null             l9_id,
         null             l9_title,
         null             l9_hierarchicode,
         l1.system_id
    from l1)

select l9_id                 ID,
       l9_title              lvl_title,
       l9_hierarchicode      hierarchicode,
       9                     lvl,
       r9."L1_ID",
       r9."L1_TITLE",
       r9."L1_HIERARCHICODE",
       r9."L2_ID",
       r9."L2_TITLE",
       r9."L2_HIERARCHICODE",
       r9."L3_ID",
       r9."L3_TITLE",
       r9."L3_HIERARCHICODE",
       r9."L4_ID",
       r9."L4_TITLE",
       r9."L4_HIERARCHICODE",
       r9."L5_ID",
       r9."L5_TITLE",
       r9."L5_HIERARCHICODE",
       r9."L6_ID",
       r9."L6_TITLE",
       r9."L6_HIERARCHICODE",
       r9."L7_ID",
       r9."L7_TITLE",
       r9."L7_HIERARCHICODE",
       r9."L8_ID",
       r9."L8_TITLE",
       r9."L8_HIERARCHICODE",
       r9."L9_ID",
       r9."L9_TITLE",
       r9."L9_HIERARCHICODE",
       r9."SYSTEM_ID"
  from r9

union all
select l8_id,
       l8_title,
       l8_hierarchicode,
       8,
       r8."L1_ID",
       r8."L1_TITLE",
       r8."L1_HIERARCHICODE",
       r8."L2_ID",
       r8."L2_TITLE",
       r8."L2_HIERARCHICODE",
       r8."L3_ID",
       r8."L3_TITLE",
       r8."L3_HIERARCHICODE",
       r8."L4_ID",
       r8."L4_TITLE",
       r8."L4_HIERARCHICODE",
       r8."L5_ID",
       r8."L5_TITLE",
       r8."L5_HIERARCHICODE",
       r8."L6_ID",
       r8."L6_TITLE",
       r8."L6_HIERARCHICODE",
       r8."L7_ID",
       r8."L7_TITLE",
       r8."L7_HIERARCHICODE",
       r8."L8_ID",
       r8."L8_TITLE",
       r8."L8_HIERARCHICODE",
       r8."L9_ID",
       r8."L9_TITLE",
       r8."L9_HIERARCHICODE",
       r8."SYSTEM_ID"
  from r8
union all

select l7_id,
       l7_title,
       l7_hierarchicode,
       7,
       r7."L1_ID",
       r7."L1_TITLE",
       r7."L1_HIERARCHICODE",
       r7."L2_ID",
       r7."L2_TITLE",
       r7."L2_HIERARCHICODE",
       r7."L3_ID",
       r7."L3_TITLE",
       r7."L3_HIERARCHICODE",
       r7."L4_ID",
       r7."L4_TITLE",
       r7."L4_HIERARCHICODE",
       r7."L5_ID",
       r7."L5_TITLE",
       r7."L5_HIERARCHICODE",
       r7."L6_ID",
       r7."L6_TITLE",
       r7."L6_HIERARCHICODE",
       r7."L7_ID",
       r7."L7_TITLE",
       r7."L7_HIERARCHICODE",
       r7."L8_ID",
       r7."L8_TITLE",
       r7."L8_HIERARCHICODE",
       r7."L9_ID",
       r7."L9_TITLE",
       r7."L9_HIERARCHICODE",
       r7."SYSTEM_ID"
  from r7
union all

select l6_id,
       l6_title,
       l6_hierarchicode,
       6,
       r6."L1_ID",
       r6."L1_TITLE",
       r6."L1_HIERARCHICODE",
       r6."L2_ID",
       r6."L2_TITLE",
       r6."L2_HIERARCHICODE",
       r6."L3_ID",
       r6."L3_TITLE",
       r6."L3_HIERARCHICODE",
       r6."L4_ID",
       r6."L4_TITLE",
       r6."L4_HIERARCHICODE",
       r6."L5_ID",
       r6."L5_TITLE",
       r6."L5_HIERARCHICODE",
       r6."L6_ID",
       r6."L6_TITLE",
       r6."L6_HIERARCHICODE",
       r6."L7_ID",
       r6."L7_TITLE",
       r6."L7_HIERARCHICODE",
       r6."L8_ID",
       r6."L8_TITLE",
       r6."L8_HIERARCHICODE",
       r6."L9_ID",
       r6."L9_TITLE",
       r6."L9_HIERARCHICODE",
       r6."SYSTEM_ID"
  from r6
union all

select l5_id,
       l5_title,
       l5_hierarchicode,
       5,
       r5."L1_ID",
       r5."L1_TITLE",
       r5."L1_HIERARCHICODE",
       r5."L2_ID",
       r5."L2_TITLE",
       r5."L2_HIERARCHICODE",
       r5."L3_ID",
       r5."L3_TITLE",
       r5."L3_HIERARCHICODE",
       r5."L4_ID",
       r5."L4_TITLE",
       r5."L4_HIERARCHICODE",
       r5."L5_ID",
       r5."L5_TITLE",
       r5."L5_HIERARCHICODE",
       r5."L6_ID",
       r5."L6_TITLE",
       r5."L6_HIERARCHICODE",
       r5."L7_ID",
       r5."L7_TITLE",
       r5."L7_HIERARCHICODE",
       r5."L8_ID",
       r5."L8_TITLE",
       r5."L8_HIERARCHICODE",
       r5."L9_ID",
       r5."L9_TITLE",
       r5."L9_HIERARCHICODE",
       r5."SYSTEM_ID"
  from r5
union all

select l4_id,
       l4_title,
       l4_hierarchicode,
       4,
       r4."L1_ID",
       r4."L1_TITLE",
       r4."L1_HIERARCHICODE",
       r4."L2_ID",
       r4."L2_TITLE",
       r4."L2_HIERARCHICODE",
       r4."L3_ID",
       r4."L3_TITLE",
       r4."L3_HIERARCHICODE",
       r4."L4_ID",
       r4."L4_TITLE",
       r4."L4_HIERARCHICODE",
       r4."L5_ID",
       r4."L5_TITLE",
       r4."L5_HIERARCHICODE",
       r4."L6_ID",
       r4."L6_TITLE",
       r4."L6_HIERARCHICODE",
       r4."L7_ID",
       r4."L7_TITLE",
       r4."L7_HIERARCHICODE",
       r4."L8_ID",
       r4."L8_TITLE",
       r4."L8_HIERARCHICODE",
       r4."L9_ID",
       r4."L9_TITLE",
       r4."L9_HIERARCHICODE",
       r4."SYSTEM_ID"
  from r4
union all

select l3_id,
       l3_title,
       l3_hierarchicode,
       3,
       r3."L1_ID",
       r3."L1_TITLE",
       r3."L1_HIERARCHICODE",
       r3."L2_ID",
       r3."L2_TITLE",
       r3."L2_HIERARCHICODE",
       r3."L3_ID",
       r3."L3_TITLE",
       r3."L3_HIERARCHICODE",
       r3."L4_ID",
       r3."L4_TITLE",
       r3."L4_HIERARCHICODE",
       r3."L5_ID",
       r3."L5_TITLE",
       r3."L5_HIERARCHICODE",
       r3."L6_ID",
       r3."L6_TITLE",
       r3."L6_HIERARCHICODE",
       r3."L7_ID",
       r3."L7_TITLE",
       r3."L7_HIERARCHICODE",
       r3."L8_ID",
       r3."L8_TITLE",
       r3."L8_HIERARCHICODE",
       r3."L9_ID",
       r3."L9_TITLE",
       r3."L9_HIERARCHICODE",
       r3."SYSTEM_ID"
  from r3
union all

select l2_id,
       l2_title,
       l2_hierarchicode,
       2,
       r2."L1_ID",
       r2."L1_TITLE",
       r2."L1_HIERARCHICODE",
       r2."L2_ID",
       r2."L2_TITLE",
       r2."L2_HIERARCHICODE",
       r2."L3_ID",
       r2."L3_TITLE",
       r2."L3_HIERARCHICODE",
       r2."L4_ID",
       r2."L4_TITLE",
       r2."L4_HIERARCHICODE",
       r2."L5_ID",
       r2."L5_TITLE",
       r2."L5_HIERARCHICODE",
       r2."L6_ID",
       r2."L6_TITLE",
       r2."L6_HIERARCHICODE",
       r2."L7_ID",
       r2."L7_TITLE",
       r2."L7_HIERARCHICODE",
       r2."L8_ID",
       r2."L8_TITLE",
       r2."L8_HIERARCHICODE",
       r2."L9_ID",
       r2."L9_TITLE",
       r2."L9_HIERARCHICODE",
       r2."SYSTEM_ID"
  from r2
union all
select l1_id,
       l1_title,
       l1_hierarchicode,
       1,
       r1."L1_ID",
       r1."L1_TITLE",
       r1."L1_HIERARCHICODE",
       r1."L2_ID",
       r1."L2_TITLE",
       r1."L2_HIERARCHICODE",
       r1."L3_ID",
       r1."L3_TITLE",
       r1."L3_HIERARCHICODE",
       r1."L4_ID",
       r1."L4_TITLE",
       r1."L4_HIERARCHICODE",
       r1."L5_ID",
       r1."L5_TITLE",
       r1."L5_HIERARCHICODE",
       r1."L6_ID",
       r1."L6_TITLE",
       r1."L6_HIERARCHICODE",
       r1."L7_ID",
       r1."L7_TITLE",
       r1."L7_HIERARCHICODE",
       r1."L8_ID",
       r1."L8_TITLE",
       r1."L8_HIERARCHICODE",
       r1."L9_ID",
       r1."L9_TITLE",
       r1."L9_HIERARCHICODE",
       r1."SYSTEM_ID"
  from r1

/*union all
select -1,'????'  , 2,
  l1_id    l1_id,
         '???? ???????? ?????? ??????' l1_title,
         -1,'????',
         null     l3_id,
         null     l3_title,
         null     l4_id,
         null     l4_title,
         null     l5_id,
         null     l5_title,
         null     l6_id,
         null     l6_title,
         null     l7_id,
         null     l7_title,
         null     l8_id,
         null     l8_title,
         null     l9_id,
         null     l9_title from
 r1;*/;
```

Answer (score 0):

What you do is some kind of `pivot`. This can be achieved with recursive CTE, but you need Oracle 11 or later. Please try this query:

```
with eval_sys_paramter as (
    -- sample test data
    select 1   id, 'P1'   parameter_name, null parent_system_parameter_id, 
           '255.255.255.1'   ip, 'S1' system_id from dual union all
    select 11  id, 'P11'  parameter_name, 1    parent_system_parameter_id, 
           '255.255.255.11'  ip, 'S1' system_id from dual union all
    select 12  id, 'P12'  parameter_name, 1    parent_system_parameter_id, 
           '255.255.255.12'  ip, 'S1' system_id from dual union all
    select 121 id, 'P121' parameter_name, 12   parent_system_parameter_id, 
           '255.255.255.121' ip, 'S1' system_id from dual ),
-- your query starts here, uncomment "with"
/* with */ t (lvl, id, ttl, pid, sid, 
        i1, t1,  p1, 
        i2, t2,  p2, 
        i3, t3,  p3 ) as (
    select 1, id, parameter_name, ip, system_id, 
           id i1, parameter_name t1, ip p1, 
           cast (null as number) i2, null t2, null p2, 
           cast (null as number) i3, null t3, null p3
      from eval_sys_paramter where parent_system_parameter_id is null
    union all
    select lvl + 1, 
           e.id, e.parameter_name, e.ip, e.system_id,
           -- level 1 
           t.i1, t.t1, t.p1, 
           -- level 2
           case lvl + 1 when 2 then e.id             else t.i2 end, 
           case lvl + 1 when 2 then e.parameter_name else t.t2 end, 
           case lvl + 1 when 2 then e.ip             else t.p2 end, 
           -- level 3
           case lvl + 1 when 3 then e.id             else t.i3 end, 
           case lvl + 1 when 3 then e.parameter_name else t.t3 end, 
           case lvl + 1 when 3 then e.ip             else t.p3 end 
      from t join eval_sys_paramter e 
               on e.system_id = t.sid 
               and e.parent_system_parameter_id = t.id )
select * from t
```

Add similar parts for levels 4-9.